# Prove that every monotone surjective function is continuous using different methods

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Prove that every monotone surjective function $f :\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous.
I need to use the theorem below to prove it:

If $f : \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is an increasing function,
$\lim_{x\to p^-} f(x)=\sup_{x<p} f(x)$, and $\lim_{x\to p^+} f(x)=\inf_{x>p} f(x)$.

I'm thinking of prove the left limit equals to the right limit. And since it's surjective, $f(p)$ is always defined. So I'll get left limit=right limit=$f(p)$, and then prove that it's continuous.
But I'm stuck when I try to prove the one-sided limits are equal.

Comment: I don't think you need $inf$ and $sup$. You can use the monotone property to choose $\delta$ for a given $\epsilon>0$, and you only need to approach $p$ from one side.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(p-) \neq f(p+)$, we must have $f(p-) < f(p+)$. Pick any $y \in (f(p-), f(p+)) \backslash \{f(p)\}$, observe that $f(x) \geq f(p+) > y$ for all $x > p$ and $f(x) \leq f(p-) < y$ for all $x < p$. This contradicts the assumption that $f$ is surjective.